# How do I read file data from a method of a FileField subclass in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a custom field in Django:

```py
from mysite.data_parsers import get_csv_data_as_dict
from mysite.validators import csv_file_validator
from django.db import models

class CSVFileField(models.FileField):
    default_validators = [csv_file_validator]

    def get_data_as_dict(self):
        # How do I read the file data here? 
        data = self.?
        return get_csv_data_as_dict(data)
```

How do I read the filedata in the method?

Comment: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/using-a-csv-file-stored-in-django-model-filefield/11121

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```py
from mysite.data_parsers import get_csv_data_as_dict
from mysite.validators import csv_file_validator
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile

class CSVFieldFile(FieldFile):
    def _get_file_data(self):
        try:
            FILE = self.open()
            return FILE.read()
        finally:
            FILE.close()

    def get_data_as_dict(self):
        data = self._get_file_data()
        return get_csv_data_as_dict(data)


class CSVFileField(models.FileField):
    default_validators = [csv_file_validator]
    attr_class = CSVFieldFile
```

If someone knows any issues with this approach, or knows of a better way, please let me know. I'm particularly interested in knowing if I'm closing the file correctly after reading it.

PS. Yes - this reads the entire file into memory, but a CSV file is never going to be too big to fit in memory (at least the ones I'm working with).